# Radio button text color issue when dynamically added

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a Radio button inside Radio groups, One Radio group is created programmatically and one from XML , Radio button which is created by XML has text color which is define in text selector, But radio button which is added programmatically not work as selector text color.

Java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        radioGroup2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg2);



        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_radio, null);;
            btn.setText("dynamic "+ i);
            btn.setId(i);
            btn.setTag(i);
            btn.setTextColor(R.drawable.radio_text_selector_type1);
            radioGroup2.addView(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

XML 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector_type1"
            android:text="text 1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector_type1"
            android:text="text 2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector_type1"
            android:text="text 3"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_product_variant_rb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:ems="7"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector_type1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

</RadioButton>
```

Selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray">
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to text color selector through XML, please use this code.

```
android:textColor="@color/radio_text_selector_type1"
```

However, if you want to set the selector programmatically, use this code -

```
radioButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.radio_text_selector_type1));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Move your radio_text_selector_type1.xml from drawable to color folder. Accept the answer if it helped. Thanks :)